# How to generate one service worker from multiple webpack builds using workbox-webpack-plugin?

Tags: webpack, service-worker, progressive-web-apps, workbox, workbox-webpack-plugin

It might sound crazy, but I am creating multi css and js files for building my app for different brands. To this, I have around 4 individual webpack file, one is for my js which is common for my all brand and 3 different css files generator. Now I wanna add `workbox-webpack-plugin` to create a `sw.js` and manifest files which would import all of the manifest files automatically.How do I do it?

So far I tried so far

```
plugins = [
  ...config.plugins,
  new InjectManifest({
    swSrc: path.resolve('./src/sw.js'),
    swDest: path.resolve('./dist/sw.js')
  }),
```

but when I do this the last webpack file override the whole output sw.js which seems fair, so I thought I will run the build one by one and give the `swSrc` of the output `sw.js` generated from the previous build, didn't workout.

How do I achieve this? Any lead please.

Comment: Instead of using the workbox-webpack-plugin, you can skip the webpack, maybe not quite ;)
Use this plugin [chunks-2-json-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/homeday-de/chunks-2-json-webpack-plugin) will generate you a json with all dependencies.
Later write a node app that loads all these dependencies and uses the workbox and builds sw.js based on these dependencies.
Maybe a little around, but more clearly. Each webpack will spit out json with what it has created and based on these json files you will build sw.js